# Android menu icon size, i dont know how to change it

Tags: android, android-studio, material-components-android, material-components, android-navigationview

I want to change the size of the icons but i dont know how. I have seen posts where people fix that but i dont understand them. Can you help me with my code?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
    <item
        android:id="@+id/page_1"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/casa"
        android:title="skere"/>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/page_2"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/map10"
        android:title="skere2"/>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/page_3"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/oferta_ic"
        android:title="skere3"/>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/page_4"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/calendario"
        android:title="skere4"/>
```

I want this icons to be bigger
[image: icons]

Comment: You could try to add extra whitespace (padding) to the images themselves

Comment: Are you using a NavigationView?

Comment: yes, im using a NavigationView

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the `NavigationView` you can use the `itemIconSize` attribute. The default value is `24dp`.
Something like:

```
<com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
    app:itemIconSize="32dp"
    ..>
```

You can also use a custom style:

```
<style name="MyNavigationView" parent="Widget.MaterialComponents.NavigationView">
  <item name="itemIconSize">...</item>
</style>
```

and then:

```
<com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
    style="@style/MyNavigationView"
    ..>
```

Standard:

[image]

After:

[image]